# Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm having a problem accessing a property that I want to use as a condition on whether or not to display a particular  element

```
<%if( (int)(Bind("DefaultAddress.AddressType"))==1)
{
%>
<td>
.....
....
</td>
<% }%>
```

This gives:

> *Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Bind' does not exist in the
>   current context*

However elsewhere on the same .aspx page I have:

```
<td class="return"  align="left">
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" Text='<%# Bind("DefaultAddress.Country") %>' runat="server" />
            </td>
```

which works perfectly. Note DefualtAddress is an instance of an Address object and Country and AddressType are properties of this object

I also tried

```
 <% if (DefaultAddress.AddressType==1)
```

but with the above code DefaultAddress is highlighted in red and when I hover over it I get the error message: Cannot resolve symbol 'DefaultAddress'

Comment: What is Bind(....)? If your function then need to use namespace at the top of view so that view engine can refer..

Comment: check u include proper assembly reference or namespace

Comment: Function Bind() is used to bind a database object with an Asp.Net control. You cannot use it in the way you have described. Rather check the condition in you database, say a procedure and return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bind` can only be used with the `<%#` tag.. if I remember correctly (WebForms was so long ago for me ... ).